# Get line separator of IFile

Tags: eclipse, newline, separator

I'm looking for a way to get the line separator of an IFile object. 
My current implementation messes up newlines on files, written on other systems, but I heavily rely on correct offsets and line numbers.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file.getContents());
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   final String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
   stringBuilder.append(nextLine + System.lineSeparator());
}
scanner.close();

Document document = new Document();
document.set(stringBuilder.toString(), document.getModificationStamp());
```

Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: Assuming your programming language is Java, correct? Not necessary to declare your String final inside a loop.  Also, you shouldn't use the concatenation operator to concatenate Strings inside a stringBuilder.append() method, that defeats the purpose of the method.  Use `stringBuilder.append(nextLine)`, then `stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator())`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a solution I stumbled upon:

```
InputStream stream = file.getContents();
Scanner s = new Scanner(stream);
s.useDelimiter("\\A");

String content = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : null;

try {
    stream.close();
s.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {      
 }

 if (content == null) {
return null;
 }

 IDocument document = new Document();
 document.set(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

See `org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.manipulation.ConvertLineDelimitersOperation.computeTextEdit(ITextFileBuffer, IProgressMonitor)`.  It uses the `IDocument.getLineDelimiter(int)` method to calculate the line delimiters in a file.

You're probably looking at something like:

```
ITextFileBufferManager manager = FileBuffersPlugin.getFileBufferManager();
ITextFileBuffer buffer = manager.getTextFileBuffer(file.getLocation());
IDocument document = buffer.getDocument();
int lineCount = document.getNumberOfLines();
for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    String delimiter = document.getLineDelimiter(i);
    // your work here
}
```